# Efficiency increase via ducting a fan - why is this more in viscous media?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fan

I am looking at mixers for liquids like water or slurries. [This brochure claims the following](http://www.xylemwatersolutions.com/scs/usa/Documents/FB004-1103_FlygtCompactMixersBrochure_sm.pdf):

> With the optional jet ring, it is possible to increase efficiency by up 15% in water - even higher in viscous media

I do not soubt that a jet ring, or ducting, can increase the efficieny of a propeller (So don't answer that). But I don not understand why this effect is stronger in viscous media. In fact, I would guess the opposite, that in a viscous media the drag of fluid - jet ring plays a bigger role, and that the centrifugal forces that propel fluid tangentially out of the propeller are less relevant in a viscous fluid. But my intuition is probably wrong, as the people selling the mixers measured something else.

**Why is the effect of the jet ring stronger with a more viscous fluid?**